# How to attach LDF file in SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to change the place of my database. but I have make one small mistake...

I have attached my db but I have not select `LDF` file therefore SQL creates one new `LDF` file. Now I want to attach my old `LDF`.

So how can I do that??

What I have tried is : first detach then delete new LDF and re-attach with old LDF but it gives me error like :

> One or more files do not match the primary file of the database. If
>   you are attempting to attach a database, retry the operation with the
>   correct files.  If this is an existing database, the file may be
>   corrupted and should be restored from a backup.

More Info. : I am using **SQL 2008 R2**

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach your old MDF and your old LDF. If you have a backup of the database then you can restore the backup. If you do not have your old MDF nor a backup, then you lost your data.